# damaged door frame

Tags: doors, frame

So I moved into my new apartment about a month and a half ago.  I immediately noticed the back door deadbolt didn't work, but I thought nothing of it since there was an additional lock that did work. I've come to find out flies are coming into my apartment through a gap created by this damaged frame. I'm trying to figure out how to do a quick repair. I tried putting a small buffer between the door and frame but it prevented the door from shutting and ultimately proved a failure. My next bet was to buy wood to fill the space and repair the deadbolt which I believe would fill in the gap.  Before taking that on I was looking for some professional advice as this is pure amateur ideas without any experience.  Below are shots of the door frame.

[image][image]

Comment: It's an apartment, which in my part of the world means it's a rented, not owned, and this is a problem to request the landlord to fix. Unless you are in one of those parts of the world where you own it but it's still called an apartment.